# Screenshot in cocoa mac

Tags: macos, nsview, nswindow

I want to achieve a screenshot functionality in cocoa app. The requirement is, After some specified time interval, a view/window (screen capture window) will appear take the screenshot of the complete screen and moves away.

I want this screen capture window to appear from the right bottom corner of the screen (Not from the main window) ?

If main window is minimized i still want this screen capture window to come, take the screenshot and go away back with animation.

Please guide me how to achieve this.

Comment: Any guidance to achieve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `screencapture` command.

> screencapture -- capture images from the screen and save them to a
>   file
>        or the clipboard

```
screencapture -mx -T0 /path/screenShot.png
```